# Double angular brackets in ASP.NET C# MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

While trying to understand `TextBoxFor()` I came across this definition in MSDN....

`TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(HtmlHelper<TModel>, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>, IDictionary<String, Object>)`

Is this just a generic class, or is it somethign else, or is it non-c# ?

(The angular brackets within angular brackets is throwing me of)

And how do you interpret it (a link would be fine - as long as its ok for beginners to C# etc).

Comment: John Laffoon posted this and then deleted it but I thought it was good so I will repost [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)

Comment: Thanks user1477388, this explins generics but I cant find where it explains the dbl generics

Comment: Check this out see if it helps.  I think the first answer explains pretty clearly what `Func<TModel, TProperty>` is used for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244669/expressionfunctmodel-tproperty-as-property-for-object-initialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a class.

`Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>` encapsulates `Func<TModel, TProperty>`, and contains extra metadata which can be used by third parties to rebuild the `Func` in their own native language.

`Func<TSrc, TDest>` represents a function that takes `TSrc` as its input, and generates an instance of `TDest` as its output.  For example, I can say:

```
var addOne = new Func<int, int>(i => i + 1);
```

and `addOne` would be a mapping that takes an integer and gives back that integer plus one.  After you've defined it, you can then call `addOne(1)`, and you'd expect that to give you 2.

The thing inside the brackets -- the i => i + 1 -- is a piece of syntax called a lambda.  Confusingly, a lambda can be used to represent both a `Func<TSrc, TDest>` and an `Expression<Func<TSrc, TDest>>`.  That is, depending on the context,

```
i => i + 1
```

represents either a `Func<int, int>` object or an `Expression<Func<int, int>>` object.  This is an example (my favourite example) of *homoiconicity* in a language.  That is, a syntax in which you can have objects of different classes represented by the same symbol, or icon.

Going back to MVC, the reason it wants an `Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>` rather than just a plan old `Func<TModel, TProperty>` is because it wants to know more about the property than what that property does with the model instance: it wants to know extra data such as the property name, its attributes, and what kind of error handling it uses.  So you can give it something like

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, ...)
```

and MVC will look up the property `FirstName` in your model and build up all sorts of HTML based on the attributes you've defined on that property.

That's more or less how it works.

Comment: Thanks do you have a link that would explain how this all works.? Or if you can tell me what I should type into google?

Comment: Sure.  There's a question about it here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct.

If you Google "Expression Func", you'll fund some links -- or "Expression Func Lambda".

Comment: I've added a few more lines of explanation myself.  Let me know if it seems like double dutch.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of nested generic type parameters.

`Expression<T>` is an open generic class that takes a single type parameter.

`Func<TModel, TProperty>` is a concrete generic delegate type that references type parameters from the surrounding generic function.

Comment: Is there a difference if I use `Expression<T>` or could I also use `Expression<var>`?  Do these do the same thing?  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Slaks, but I dont understand what 'concrete generic delegate type that references type parameters from the surrounding generic function' means. I'm looking more for an explanation rather than a definition (i dont mean to be rude)

Answer (score 2):

It's just a nested generic type.

An `Expression` of type `Func` of type `TModel, TProperty`

Answer (score 1):

A class with nested generic type parameters.

**The inner part:**

```
Func<TModel, TProperty>
```

A delegate, referencing ("describing") a function that takes the generic type `TModel` as an argument and returns a result of generic type `TProperty`, e.g.:

```
TProperty MyFunc(TModel model)
```

... which corresponds to the types in the usual argument to `TextBoxFor()`:

```
model => model.Name
```

`model` is of type `TModel` and `model.Name` is of type `TProperty`.

**The outer part:**

```
Expression<T>
```

An expression tree describing a lambda expression (delegate) of the type `T`. The `Expression<T>` generic class allows you to (in simplified terms) examine the *code itself* at runtime rather than the result of executing it. In other words, the `TextBoxFor()` method can e.g. extract the actual name of the property (`Name` in the above example), in addition to compiling the expression and executing it to get the result.

If we simply took a `Func<>` as an argument, we would only be able to call the passed delegate and get the result of that call, rather than examining it in this kind of detail.

For the HTML helpers, the use of expression trees is mainly a type safe alternative to the `TextBox()` methods, which take the name of the property as a string.

**So, in combination:**

```
Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>
```

A parameter to `TextBoxFor()` that is "An expression tree describing: a lambda expression that takes a parameter of the generic type `TModel` and returns a property of the generic type `TProperty`".

The nested generics aren't limited to something as relatively advanced as expression trees. A simpler, concrete, example of nested generics is this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>>
```

A dictionary with `string`s for keys, and `List`s of `int`s as values.